# Analog of NLua that helps to run pascal scripts from C#

Tags: c#, dll, pascal

Do you know any libraries that can help to run pascal scripts from C#? Yes, I know that's an awful idea, but...i have no choose...

**P.S. Sorry for my ugly English!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the pascal code to a DLL with a compiler like [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org), and interface it using [C# interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx).

Note that COM compatible SEH is default for 64-bit DLLs, but needs recompilation of FPC for 32-bits DLLs (-dtest_win32_seh)